# Explanation of gcc optimization

Tags: c, performance, optimization, gcc

Out of hacker curiosity, I wonder how `gcc` can manage to optimize the function below this smartly?

```
int c() {
        int i, j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                j += i;
        }
        return j;
}
```

`$objdump -D c.o` below is for arm but x86 is no different in logic.

```
00000000 <c>:
   0:   202d        movs    r0, #45 ; 0x2d
   2:   4770        bx  lr
```

I mostly wonder if this is result of a chain of optimizations or something like a template match? Are there any documentation on such optimizations?

Comment: retaging with c will atract more people...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The optimizer does this in phases/passes... when you specify -O2 there are many optimizations that are enabled.  The principal optimizations that come into play here are

1. [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding)
2. [constant propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding#Constant_propagation)
3. [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding#Constant_folding)
4. [dead-code elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

so this code

```
int i, j = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    j += i;
}
return j;
```

after loop unrolling becomes

```
int i, j = 0;
i=0; j += i;
i=1; j += i;
i=2; j += i;
i=3; j += i;
i=4; j += i;
i=5; j += i;
i=6; j += i;
i=7; j += i;
i=8; j += i;
i=9; j += i;
return j;
```

after constant propagation pass

```
int i, j = 0;
i=0; j += 0;
i=1; j += 1;
i=2; j += 2;
i=3; j += 3;
i=4; j += 4;
i=5; j += 5;
i=6; j += 6;
i=7; j += 7;
i=8; j += 8;
i=9; j += 9;
return j;
```

after dead-code elimination

```
j = 0;
j += 0;
j += 1;
j += 2;
j += 3;
j += 4;
j += 5;
j += 6;
j += 7;
j += 8;
j += 9;
return j;
```

after [constant folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding#Constant_folding)

```
j = 45;
return j;
```

and finally,

```
return 45;
```

Comment: Sorry to down vote on an old answer, but this isn't an accurate depiction of the transforms GCC performs (though it does work, and is a sensible approximation and neat demonstration of various compiler optimizations). If you would like to see GCC's internal working for this testcase, you can pass -fdump-tree-cunroll-all and read the output. My main objection is that most of these analysis are intertwined, GCC only decides to unroll because it knows it can fold away the induction variable and cunroll does the folding/propagation so there is never any dead code to eliminate.