# terminology: how can one say a program has more data than instructions when the concept of data and instruct can't be seperated?

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu, cpu-architecture

This is a question about terminology. I use ARM as an example since it's the only assembly I'm familiar with but am looking for more general answers.

Basically I'm having trouble distinguishing between an instruction, data and opcodes.

I red that GPUs tend to make more memory accesses than CPUs do because graphics computations tend to be data heavy. My question basically is, what is data in the context of processors because processors can only execute instructions?

Does it make sense to say 25% of a program is instructions and 75% is data?

In ARM assembly, is anything after included in the `.data` section considered data as opposed to data? Do operands ever count as data? For example if I do `mov R0, #5` is it correct to say the entire line is the instruction, mov is the opcode and 5 is the data?

In the `.text` section if you have `ldr R0, =myVar` and in the `.data` section have `myVar: .word 5` what would be considered the instruction and what would be considered the opcode?

Does every instruction have both data and opcode? But then how can statements like "GPUs typically handel more data than instructions" make sense?

EDIT: let me reword the question. In terms of an L1 cahce specific to data and an L1 cache specific to instructions, how is it distinguised (on the assembly level) if something is a data or instruction? It seems like poor wording because everything the CPU executes is an instruction.

Comment: Obviously you can process a lot of data, with a small set of instruciton, so why should this statement be surprising? Databases regularly process data in the gigabyte range, but the code never even comes close to that.

Comment: I think you're confused between the notions of "data/code size" and "volume of data/code access". They don't have to correlate. One variable accessed 100500 times takes little memory but generates a lot of CPU/memory traffic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fair to say everything CPU executes is an instruction *and everything it loads is data*...

Since you are wondering about terminology and question is tagged cpu-architecture...

Any modern mainstream computer architecture including ARM can be classified as [Modified Harvard  Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Harvard_architecture) where:

> The Harvard architecture is a computer architecture with physically
>   separate storage and signal pathways for instructions and data. (A modified Harvard architecture machine is very much like a Harvard architecture machine, but it relaxes the strict separation between instruction and data while still letting the CPU concurrently access two (or more) memory buses.)

So there you have the definition of data and instruction as good as you can find. What it simply tells is cpu has two streams of input, instruction telling what to do and data allowing to load/store bits of information. So anything loaded from data port is data.

Nice thing about such separation, people who are creating cpu architectures can take decisions on their plans and add extra features to optimize different parts. Meaning data port can have more expensive memory access interface.

> Do operands ever count as data?

I guess it depends if you think constant data as data. It is obvious you can't embed variable information as opcodes but to my understanding as long as computer architecture goes operands are not data.

Just think you have some instructions with just operands. Like an algorithm calculating some number. If all the data is constant, why would you need the algorithm anyway? You would have the [perfect optimization case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14953649/1163019) where a good system would just return the result instead of doing the exact same steps all over.

From another point, comparing CPU and GPU, GPU is a specific CPU which is good at bulk processing lots of data as you heard.

Imagine you want to convert a colored image to a grey scale one. Simply you want to change each pixel to a greyish one. The way you would do is to load a pixel (your data) do some calculation and store it back. How you could do improve such task via hardware means? You can improve your memory interface to have better sequential access, improve your cpu to do calculations suitable for pixel work, increase number of cpus that can work in parallel... but then Voila! you have a GPU on your hands.

Problem in designing and manufacturing hardware is full with trade offs because of the costs. So in reality if you would try to implement a CPU as good as a GPU you need to remove some other features to keep the cost balanced.

If you do that then some other specific type of tasks would run worse on your new CPU. I think best example would be an OS, which I believe has the greatest instruction to data processing ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there will be a real answer to this because the terms you are confused about are equally vague to us.

ARM uses a fixed length instruction set.  with a variable length, x86 for example, if you want to load a 32 bit immediate in some register you have some opcode byte or few and then the 32 bit immediate which sits there in .text with the instructions.  with a fixed length like mips or arm, it really is no different instead of a load immediate of some 32 bit number you will sometimes have that 32 bit number nearby in .text but you will do a pc relative load instruction which is a data cycle rather than a fetch cycle.  If that is what you are trying to isolate, good luck with that.  Many times at compile time if there is an external reference (variable or function basically an address) then the compiler usually allocates space that the linker then fills in.  For a variable length instruction set the compiler would simply choose the far call or jump or mov which is the same thing a bogus address is left there for the linker to fill in later.

Old processors like the x86 and 6502 and z80 and some that were related had more of a notion of an opcode where the bit pattern didnt really tell you what registers were what, the opcode map may have been carved out in Karnaugh map style for easier decoding but the what those groups of instructions did were not necessarily directly from the opcode bits.  RISC and more modern instruction sets (even some of the x86 instructions) are more obvious where most of the instruction is just the gprs and only a few bits are called the opcode say an alu instruction a few bits will pic add from sub from and from or, but to get to decode those opcode bits you have to decode other bits.  ARM's encoding is very not obvious, the bits you have to look at to see what instruction it is are all over the place.  Mips on the other hand has a few major classes and by doing two or three inspections you know what instruction it is.  So the term opcode vs data just doesnt really make much sense anymore, I would say with ARM the instruction can have both data and opcode, not so much as the x86 does, but still some of the instructions do.

As far as .data vs .text it is extremely application specific and there can be no answer, gpu, cpu, or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

"how can statements like "GPUs typically handel more data than instructions" make sense?" GPU's typically apply one instruction at a time to a set of data. So the number of instruction fetches is small compared to the number of data fetches. It's a form of stream processing. Wiki article: [stream processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_processing) .